# Get the amount of lines of a string in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How do I get the amount of lines of a string in xaml? 
I have the following string:

```
string test = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non 
sapien ac est suscipit luctus ut ut nulla. Nulla vitae turpis id nisl ultrices 
lacinia. Mauris laoreet lectus eu urna congue dapibus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam 
tincidunt diam congue lectus ullamcorper placerat. In sed vehicula sem, sit 
amet laoreet felis.";
```

I've put this string into a frame in xaml. It looks like this:

[image: frame]

How do I get the amount of lines of the string inside of the frame?

I tried the following:

```
int numLines = (int)lbl_txt_Tijdstip5_Lang.LineHeight;
Debug.Write(numLines);
```

However, this returned `-1`, where it should return `24` in this case.

**Edit:**

Xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="10" TranslationX="12.5" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="295">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label x:Name="lbl_Tijdstip6" FontSize="26" TextColor="#CD5C52" TranslationY="0" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Start"/>
                <Label x:Name="lbl_txt_Tijdstip6_Lang" FontSize="17" XAlign="Center" TranslationY="0" YAlign="End"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: could you post the xaml code corresponding?

Comment: @Frenchy I edited it.

Comment: you put the string into lbl_txt_Tijdstip6_Lang?

Comment: @Frenchy Yep sorry, forgot to change it into 'Test'

Comment: By first, `LineHeight` property set the space between lines, not the amount of lines. Second, the amount of lines would change depending on the device size. And by last, why do you need to get the amount of lines?

Comment: You can get the length of string  and the width of label,then calculate number of lines.

Comment: @FabriBertani I know that the amount of lines depend on the device, but I thought that there might be something to still calculate it. I want to create a formula for the frame's height to adjust to the amount of lines.

Comment: @johnheaven, I will try it out thank you.

Comment: @johnheaven how do I calculate it like that? How do I get the label's widht?

Comment: Using `labelOne.Width` can get,and you should get the right length of string.